# Data Storage options for iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I am building an app that will require an offline mode when unable to get a wifi or data connection.

I am wondering what is the best solution for the following scenario.

Lets say my app allows users to view, add , amend an event on a calendar.

For the app to work off line i only need to store the current days worth of events. This could be be between 1 - 10 events. Each event will have a name, description and various other small properties.

I have been looking at coreData and am wondering if this maybe a bit overkill for what i need. I don't need to mirror the whole DB or anything like that.

Can I constructively use NSUserDefaults to store this king of information.
What are NSUserDefaults limitations in terms of what types you can store and how much.

The off line version will possibly need to store more entities than just the above so is it a viable method of storing data providing the amount of data is't massive.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: How are you storing data when your online ?

Comment: my app has a full backend db with scripts etc for online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### NSUserDefaults

- `NSUserDefaults` is really meant for storing small pieces of data such as settings, preferences, and individual values.
- `NSUserDefaults` offers a trivial learning curve and thread safe implementation.

#### CoreData

- Learning curve may be a bit steep
- `CoreData` and related classes provide easy ways to get your entities into UITableViews, like `NSFetchedResultsController`.
- `CoreData` abstracts away a lot of the messy things you'd otherwise have to deal with yourself, such as lists of objects, one-to-many or many-to-many relationships, or constraints on object attributes, into a single nice clean object-oriented interface
- `CoreData` manages save and undo functionality for you. It has a persistent store, which tracks changes, and can be flushed to the disk automatically at any number of times

However, if you're new to Cocoa I would avoid `CoreData`, to give yourself a chance to learn the basics first.

If I had to choose I would dive directly into `CoreData`. It makes sense also for small projects. `NSUserDefaults` is not meant to be used as a database (all the operations are ran on the main thread).

Comment: Thanks i think CoreData is the way to go, head first i think :-) do you know of any good tutorial for coreData, i have found a few but they skimmed over a lot of functionality.

Comment: CoreData is a very broad topic and it's  gonna be hard to find one tutorial that covers everything. I like tutorials from Ray Wenderlich. You can check this one out http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Comment: One lecture series and two books... on iTunes U watch Paul Hegarty's amazing Stanford lectures on iOS. Apart from that highly recommend reading 1. http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/; 2. from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013) by Marcus Zarra; 3. from Apress publishers – "Pro iOS Persistence Using Core Data", by Michael Privat and Robert Warner.

Answer (score 0):

Coredata may be an overkill at first, but as your app grows so does your datamodel. CoreData is designed for such changes.

NSUserDefaults will store anything as long as the object complies to the NSCoding protocol, but its not meant to store a lot of information. Besides that, it can be difficult to fetch the data in NSUserDefaults, while it is rather easy in CoreData. Also note that relations between objects are unmanageable when storing objects in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Actually, NSUserDefaults only support property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects. There is a way to convert any object, that implements NSCoding to NSData, using NSArchiver, trough.